# How to diagnose eye diagram slope on physical impedance problems?

Tags: eye-diagram

When looking at the eye diagram as shown bellow, if we have high rise time which is cause by RC properties, what can we say about the impedance? What could cause bad rise time?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

well, you say the cause is an RC thing. Answer yourself this question: is it the R or the C that limits the slope? It's both. so, your signal source can't charge the C infinitely fast due to the R, and the C is what needs to be charged before the output reaches the input voltage.

Thus, your impedance has both a real and an imaginary part – it's an RC, alright.

Comment: In a number of high speed standards, there are *minimum* rise and fall times to control EMI; usually implemented by limiting the current in the drivers.

Comment: Hello, why increase in the data speed then the slope is decreased? ( high rise time)

Comment: @rocko445 having less steep edges doesn't mean you can't use the data anymore! The slope really only has to be steep enough so that you get a good opening at the right symbol sampling instant. Timing recovery is a separate problem, but even that doesn't benefit *that* much from steeper slopes.

Comment: hello, what causes us to get less steep edges from high data speed?

Comment: us designing the circuitry to do exactly that. It is typically a combination limiting drive strength in bipolar driver stages, or intentionally introducing Miller effects, or limiting the speed at which FET gates are charged through series resistors, or…

Comment: Hello Marcus,i was talking about the speed and its effect on the slope.
why if we have higher speed then the slope gets worse.
my logic says that the slope cannot change at all.
if we put higher speed then our output capacitance will charge to less value thus creating the upper wall.
But i cant see the effect on the slope

Comment: no, if you have higher speed the slope doesn't inherently get worse. Are you perhaps using something that has a maximum slope, and then you try to use it for higher speeds, and thus you scale your eye diagram's time-axis differently, and conclude the slope gets slower?

Comment: Hello,why did you say that having a slope is not a problem.
A low slope means we can much more voltages between 0 and VDD thus we can get confused.

Comment: that only happens when it's **too** slow to reach full voltage at the sampling point. It really doesn't matter how slow it is between the best sampling instants, really, as long as it reaches the full voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The slope is not the issue here.  It is often limited by the channel (fibre) at capacity or the Rx filter BW in order to raise the SNR of the signal.

The real issue is group delay (GD) distortion from different spectrum signal patterns and results in jitter or Inter Symbol Inference (ISI). 0011 vs 1010 vs 100100 etc